# What are the factors involved in deciding on .NET framework version?

Tags: .net

My title sums it up.  I have a simple Line of Business application that I will be developing and am curious how to go about determining which version of .NET I should target.  Support for Win XP SP3 would be nice, but not necessary.  It is going to be used to index multi-page tiffs, so import a batch of tiffs, then index them in a database.  Users can then conduct simple searches to find those tiffs.

What do most developers look at when trying to determine the .NET framework they will target for a new application like this?  Do I just target 4.5 since it's newest or highest version that supports what I need?

Comment: I would suggest to go for the 4.5 version as you need to start.I am working in 4.0 as we have started project two year ago and 4.5 was not available...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its always better to target(if you have the budget) the latest version of .NET as in a couple of years, its gonna be the old version :). The latest version will have new libraries and new methods and properties which will make coding easy for you.

Comment: Thanks that makes enough sense to me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

4.0 + 4.5 have lots of great functionality which wasn't previously available - particularly tasks and await/async - I think the 2012 UI seems quicker too.  I would advocate starting with the latest, as it can be a pain to upgrade and it'll buy you some time.

Added - the one thing preventing my work from upgrading at the moment is the lack of support for visual studio setup projects, which we currently use (.net 3.5).  When we do move,  we'll probably bite the bullet and change over to WIX.

Worth keeping this in mind if you have any older projects installed this way.  ([no more vs setup support](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/03/17/visual-studio-setup-projects-vdproj-will-not-ship-with-future-versions-of-vs.aspx))